# Laravel 4: Two different view pages for a single URI based on auth status

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have recently got into developing with Laravel 4 and I had a question about routes.

For '/', I would like to have two different view pages based on the user's auth status.

If a user is logged in and is viewing '/', I would like to show them a view with admin controls and when a user is viewing '/' as a regular user without logging in, I would like to offer a general information view.

To accomplish this, I've been playing around with filter 'auth' and 'guest' but am having no luck.
// app/routes.php

```
// route for logged in users
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
   return 'logged in!';
}));

// for normal users without auth
Route::get('/', function() 
{ 
    return 'not logged in!'; 
}));
```

The above code works to a point where the as a logged in user, I am able to display the proper response but after logging out, I cannot see the proper response as a regular user.

Perhaps this is something that should be handled in the controller? If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One (simple) option would be to use the [`Auth::check()`](http://laravel.com/docs/security) function to see if they are logged in:

```
Route::get('/', function() 
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        return 'logged in!';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'not logged in!'; 
    }  
});
```

You would be able to use the same logic in the controller if you so wish.

**EDIT - using filters**

If you wanted to do this in the filter, you could use something like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('non-admin-home');
    }
});
```

and then defining a second route (or action in your controller) to handle the normal users.  Though this would mean a different url for the page, which I don't think is what you want..

**COMPLETE CONTROLLER-BASED ROUTING FLOW:** (keeping `routes.php` clean)

*routes.php*

```
Route::controller('/', 'IndexController');
```

*IndexController.php*

```
class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    // HOME PAGE
    public function getIndex()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            return View::make('admin.home');
        }
        else
        {
            return View::make('user.home');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! This is the logical way to do it but I was unsure if putting if statements in the routes file was a standard way of doing things. I guess theres no rules against it if this is not doable with the built in route class.

Comment: yeah, I know what you mean.. though it is clean and easy to follow the logic.  An alternative could be to use a filter to redirect the user to another view.. I'll update the above with something..

Comment: It's common practise to do what you want to do from within the view, as your only intention is to change what is displayed to the user. In such a case, you need not do your routing like the above. You simply need to apply the check from within a view. However, if you intend to change output controller logic that gets sent to the view before rendering it, then you would need to do the above.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I have successfully implemented the filters method which seems to make the most sense!

Comment: Thank you for including the controller example.  Want to keep routes "skinny" because they get messy fast in non-trivial applications.