# Laravel login and admin panel (after successful authentication) pages both on "/"

Tags: session, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to have the login of my application and the admin panel (accessed after successful login) both accessible on "/".

I use the create method of a SessionsController for the login part (SessionsController.php):

class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

```
/**
* Show the form for creating a new resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function create()
{
    if ( Auth::check() ) return Redirect::to('homeAdmin');
    //return View::make('homeLogin');
    return View::make('homeLogin');
}
// Other methods, store, destroy...
```

}

I have my routes set like this (routes.php):

```
<?php

// Home page as guest displays a login form
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homeLogin', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@create']);

// Authentication via the SessionsControlle
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController');

// Pages for logged in users
Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function()
{
    // Home page with admin panel for authenticated users
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homeAdmin']);

    // Other pages from admin panel
    Route::get('manageThis', ['as' => 'manageThis']);
    Route::get('manageThat', ['as' => 'manageThat']);
});
```

And the filters are unchanged, ie (filters.php):

```
<?php

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});

Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

The thing is that I am constantly redirected to '/login' instead of to the 'homeLogin' route. I guess there is something to change in the guest filter but when I edited it, it got even worse and didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting homeLogin within a guest group? So like...

```
Route::group(['before' => 'guest'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homeLogin', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@create']);
});
```

Otherwise you can manually check this in your controller/route programatically:

```
if(!Auth::user()) { 
    return View::make('guest.page'); 
}
```

For further info, check this answer also: [Laravel 4: Two different view pages for a single URI based on auth status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048105/laravel-4-two-different-view-pages-for-a-single-uri-based-on-auth-status?rq=1)

Comment: I just tried it but it still redirects to '/login', I suppose it comes from the filter settings with return Redirect::guest('login') because when I chande 'login' there, it's the page where I land. The problem is, that when I put '/', it still end on '/login' and when I put another name, I am redirected to this name.

Comment: @IamZesh Gotcha! I had this problem also, I ended up putting in a custom redirect in my controller



    if(!Auth::user()) {
        return View::make('guest.page');
    }

Comment: This answer might contain what you might need also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048105/laravel-4-two-different-view-pages-for-a-single-uri-based-on-auth-status?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! If you edit your answer (either providing the link that you put in the comment or putting a sum up of the solution) I can mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @IamZesh Done :) Glad to have been a help!

Answer (score 0):

Route should be one and programatically check on controller for both login view and dashboard view.You have two routes for this process.

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homeLogin', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@create']);

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homeAdmin']);
```

Delete one and check it on controller like this:

```
if(Auth::user()) { 
    return View::make('dashboard')->with('datas', $yourDatabaseQureiesForDashboard); 
}
else
{
    return View::make('login'); 
}
```